# I am unable to add two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to add two columns in a dataframe. I am unable to ckeck their properties.
How can I go about it?

```
import re
import textwrap
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame

URL = "https://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=536&comp_id=1&teamTabs=results"
# URL = "http://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/countries-by-gdp/"
r = requests.get(URL)

# soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'soccerGrid'})


def rowgetdatatext(tr, coltag='td', true=None):  # td (data) or th (header)
    cols = []
    for td in tr.find_all(coltag):
        cols.append(td.get_text(strip=true))
    return cols


def tabledatatext(table):
    rows = []
    trs = table.find_all('tr')
    headerow = rowgetdatatext(trs[0], 'th')
    if headerow:  # if there is a header row include first
        rows.append(headerow)
        trs = trs[1:]
    for tr in trs:  # for every table row
        rows.append(rowgetdatatext(tr, 'td'))  # data row
    return rows


d = tabledatatext(table)

pd.set_option('display.width', 400)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 20)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

Frame = pd.DataFrame(df.values,
                     columns=["Competition", "Date", "Omit", "Home Team", "Score", "Away Team", "Omit",
                              "Omit", "Omit", "DateKeep"
                              ])
Frame = Frame.drop(columns=["Omit", "Date"])
Frame = Frame.drop([0, 1], axis=0)

Frame[['Home Score', 'Away Score']] = Frame['Score'].str.split('-', expand=True)
Frame = Frame.drop(columns="Score")
Frame = Frame[["Competition", "Home Team", "Home Score", "Away Team", "Away Score",
               "DateKeep"]]

Frame['Home Team'] = Frame['Home Team'].str[:-20]
Frame['Away Team'] = Frame['Away Team'].str[:-20]
Frame['DateKeep'] = Frame['DateKeep'].str[3:]
Frame['Competition'] = Frame['Competition'].str[:-18]

# Frame['Home Score'] = Frame['Home Score'].str.split()
# Frame['Away Score'] = Frame['Away Score'].str.split()

# pd.to_numeric(Frame['Away Score'], errors='coerce')
F2 = Frame.index(Frame)
print(Frame)
print(F2)
```

A sample output is:

Competition       Home Team Home Score       Away Team Away Score           DateKeep
2                       Premier League Premier League         Man Utd         4          Chelsea          0  2019-08-11 16:30 
3               European Super Cup European Super Cup       Liverpool         2          Chelsea          2  2019-08-14 20:00 
4                       Premier League Premier League         Chelsea         1        Leicester          1  2019-08-18 16:30 
5                       Premier League Premier League         Norwich         2          Chelsea          3  2019-08-24 12:30 
6                       Premier League Premier League         Chelsea         2        Sheff Utd          2  2019-08-31 15:00 
7                       Premier League Premier League          Wolves         2          Chelsea          5  2019-09-14 15:00

If I want to add the Home Score & the Away Score columns, it concats the two values instead of adding.
Where am I not getting it?
Thanks
Edit: Adding screenshot of current output & Desired output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCAim.png)

Comment: can you show the output you've and one you want?

Comment: You can do it by image(screen shoot) or markdown. Just edit your question.

Comment: Just added the image of what I get and what I want. I have tried so many things. The best I have got is [2,2] as sum.

Comment: Presumably it's concatenating values because they are strings. Convert the columns to a numeric datatype after stripping the strings down to just the numeric values.

Comment: When I added this code: Frame[['Total Score', 'Away Score']] = Frame[['Total Score', 'Away Score']].apply(pd.to_numeric) I get this error:
File "C:/Users/harsh/PycharmProjects/Web Scraping/Code1.1.py", line 65, in <module>
    Frame['Away Score'] = Frame['Away Score'].astype(int)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\PycharmProjects\We.......... return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 547, in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Man.. I wanna build a data confidence AI.. Even the first steps are mountains to climb.. :P But I will

Comment: Some of your values are null (`None`) which make no sense to convert to int. You need to explicitly fill those or ignore them to proceed to convert the column to an int.

Comment: Can you please help me with the code? Please.

Comment: Is my dataframe locked?

Comment: Seriously man.. just getting tables in python is not easy.. I wanna clean the dataset.. keep just the matches which have been completed.. Have then for like a 100 such pages/teams.. and save it into an access databse. I have created the access database..

Comment: I get an output till this stage[link](https://imgur.com/CQdfUZa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would gather a list of each column of interest's values using the length of one of the scores columns to limit the other columns list size to being the same. Then zip those lists and convert to df. You can calculate last two columns provided you have converted prior scores columns into ints.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = ['Competition','Home Team','Home Score','Away Team','Away Score','Date Keep','Total Score (Home + Away Score)','Goal Difference (Home - Away Score)']
r = requests.get('https://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=536&comp_id=1&teamTabs=results')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

h_scores = [int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em:first-child')]
a_scores = [int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em + em')]
total_scores = [h+a for h,a in zip(h_scores, a_scores)]
diff_scores = [h-a for h,a in zip(h_scores, a_scores)]
limit = len(a_scores)
comps = [i.text for i in soup.select('.tournament a', limit=limit)]
dates = [i.text for i in soup.select('.dateTime .hide', limit=limit)]
h_teams = [i.text for i in soup.select('.homeTeam a', limit=limit)]
a_teams = [i.text for i in soup.select('.awayTeam a', limit=limit)]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(comps, h_teams, h_scores, a_teams, a_scores, dates, total_scores, diff_scores), columns = headers)
print(df)
```

Comment: Where does my code come in? I ran just this code and i got this [link](https://imgur.com/11CmGXV)

Comment: your code won't work as is. You are targeting the wrong level nodes for data and not converting to ints.

Comment: Mate.. can you help me just to write my datafdrame to my database? Or make it calcutable? What should my code be?

Comment: Hi QHarr, Can we chat and you can help me out of this issue? My chat id is harshadbarge@gmail.com

Comment: hi, it's 3.30am here - if no one else has answered this in the way you want by the time I finish work I will open a room and invite you to give some pointers.

Comment: Yes.. and the response I got was: [link](https://imgur.com/3EE3aDm)

Comment: you need to install lxml parser

Comment: Thats great @QHarr Let me know the best time to do this. Sensei!

Comment: or switch to slower parser with soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

Comment: ^^ run with that parser instead

Comment: I am on on python 3.7.3 I dont have a compatible xml parser?

Comment: to use lxml you need lxml installed. You should have html.parser by default. Either will work here.

Comment: Hey! Look at that!.. Atleast the edit worked. Now "Away Scores" Is defined? [link](https://imgur.com/t3x1BZp)

Comment: Sorry, I edited to shorter names but missed one. Jupyter, of course, remembered the old so didn't throw an error. Use: limit = len(a_scores)    - answer edited.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202299/discussion-between-py-noob-and-qharr).